# Does RAM frequency & or Latency affect Internet browsing speed or page loading

Tags: windows-10, memory, cpu, cpu-usage

I currently have 3000 mhz, cl 15. RAM. (8600k so no CPU bottleneck etc)

But i was wondering if someone with more knowledge would be able to tell me if i bought 
**3200 mhz**  **CL 14**, RAM would it affect my system at all, i.e internet speed or even program loading speed. Would it make any difference at all?

Comment: Likely yes but you won't be able to notice it. The RAM speed usually accounts for a small percentage of performance increase. More so with such "lax" application such as regular internet browsing. In addition you'd need to account for what you already have. For example the impact of 3000 to 3200 is going to be way smaller than 2133 to 3200. It's still only going to be a very small percentage.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer, is there anything you would personally recommend to increase my system performance, in regards to internet browsing and "responsiveness" of general use?
(with cost not being a factor)
(besides adding another Nvme, or upgrading my internet plan) (both of which were already done).

Comment: "Cost not being a factor" is a wonderful phrase.  Assuming you're running a desktop.  You're running an intel 8600K so it's using socket FCLGA1151.  If you built the PC, then you can use the same socket for an i9-9700K. If it's a brand-name PC, upgrading CPU is not always possible and will void the warranty.  There's many details that go into upgrading hardware / building new PCs.

Comment: @James personally, if it was just internet browsing, I wouldn't bother. As mentioned the increases are usually very small (1-2% maybe?). I'd rather look at the size (4 GB, 8 GB, 16 GB etc.) and the other components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Questions like "Does increasing RAM speed improve perceived performance?" have been asked before ...  Generally, the answer is "Yes, but not very much."  You can buy RAM rated higher than 3200.  There's a great deal to learn before memory overclocking.  An important step is to enable XMP Extended Memory Profile in your BIOS.

[RAM speed: How does it impact performance?](https://superuser.com/questions/204694/ram-speed-how-does-it-impact-performance)

[Measure ram speed for application/ current speed utilization](https://superuser.com/questions/1222074/measure-ram-speed-for-application-current-speed-utilization)

[Performance related to ram speed](https://superuser.com/questions/663851/performance-related-to-ram-speed)